# Route websocket client messages to websocket server

Tags: python, websocket, python-asyncio, fastapi

I'm trying to ingest data from an external WebSocket using Websocket Client A and send those messages to WebSocket Server B for clients connected to B to view. (Reason being, I'm trying to connect multiple external WebSockets and feed their messages to a single point, if this is a bad design can someone suggest an alternative)

Running server B `uvicorn server:app --reload` then visit `http://127.0.0.1:8000/`

WebSocket Server B

```py
from typing import List

from fastapi import FastAPI, WebSocket, WebSocketDisconnect
from fastapi.responses import HTMLResponse

app = FastAPI()

html = """
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Screener</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h2>Your ID: <span id="ws-id"></span></h2>
        <ul id='messages'>
        </ul>
        <script>
            var client_id = Date.now()
            document.querySelector("#ws-id").textContent = client_id;
            var ws = new WebSocket(`ws://localhost:8000/ws/${client_id}`);
            ws.onmessage = function(event) {
                var messages = document.getElementById('messages')
                var message = document.createElement('li')
                var content = document.createTextNode(event.data)
                message.appendChild(content)
                messages.appendChild(message)
            };
            function sendMessage(event) {
                var input = document.getElementById("messageText")
                ws.send(input.value)
                input.value = ''
                event.preventDefault()
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
"""


class ConnectionManager:
    def __init__(self):
        self.active_connections: List[WebSocket] = []

    async def connect(self, websocket: WebSocket):
        await websocket.accept()
        self.active_connections.append(websocket)

    def disconnect(self, websocket: WebSocket):
        self.active_connections.remove(websocket)

    async def send_personal_message(self, message: str, websocket: WebSocket):
        await websocket.send_text(message)

    async def broadcast(self, message: str):
        for connection in self.active_connections:
            await connection.send_text(message)


manager = ConnectionManager()


@app.get("/")
async def get():
    return HTMLResponse(html)


@app.websocket("/ws/{client_id}")
async def websocket_endpoint(websocket: WebSocket, client_id: int):
    await manager.connect(websocket)
    try:
        while True:
            data = await websocket.receive_text()
            await manager.send_personal_message(f"You wrote: {data}", websocket)
            await manager.broadcast(f"Client #{client_id} says: {data}")
    except WebSocketDisconnect:
        manager.disconnect(websocket)
        await manager.broadcast(f"Client #{client_id} left the chat")
```

WebSocket ClientA

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
import websocket
import _thread
import time
import asyncio
import websockets

from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor

_EXECUTOR_ = ThreadPoolExecutor(1)

async def main_loop():
  async with websockets.connect("ws://localhost:8000/ws/1") as server_ws:
    await server_ws.send("main_loop")
    
    def send_message(message):
      server_ws.send(message)

    def ws_message(ws, message):
      loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
      loop.run_in_executor(_EXECUTOR_, send_message, message)
      print("WebSocket thread: %s" % message)

    def ws_open(ws):
      ws.send('{"event":"subscribe", "subscription":{"name":"trade"}, "pair":["XBT/USD","XRP/USD"]}')

    def ws_thread(*args):
      ws = websocket.WebSocketApp("wss://ws.kraken.com/", on_open = ws_open, on_message = ws_message)
      ws.run_forever()

    _thread.start_new_thread(ws_thread, ())

    while True:
        time.sleep(5)
        print("Main thread: %d" % time.time())

asyncio.run(main_loop())
```

Answer (score 0):

What is the question?

WS is kind of a multiplex connection that allows each side (server/client or whatever) to both send and receive messages in an asynchronous way. Ingesting data from one side of the WS (in your case Client A) and consuming some related data through another API is OK - it all depends on your needs.

This approach kind of reminds me of a classic Pub/Sub pattern. Where you have an API that you ingest data through and pass it to a Queue (RabbitMQ, Google Pub/Sub service/AWS SNS) the messages ingested into the queue are being consumed by another service that parses the data and populates some DB,
Then any other client can access a third service (API) to consume the relevant data.

Nice explanation about the Pub/Sub pattern [Link1](https://ably.com/topic/pub-sub#:%7E:text=The%20Publish%2FSubscribe%20pattern%2C%20also,the%20publisher%20to%20the%20subscribers.), [Link2](https://aws.amazon.com/pub-sub-messaging/)
Not sure what advantage WebSockets provide in your example

Comment: Yes it is replicating pubsub. I need a fast (dev time) way of pub sub for users to receive web socket feed data from multiple exchanges websocket a via one end user websocket connection.

Comment: So what is the question? Is that pattern acceptable for Dev? You can do whatever you want... I'd recommend to abstract the Pub/Sub implementation away, and when needed you can replace the underlying queue with whatever implementation you wish (RabbitMQ, Google Pub/Sub service/AWS SNS)